# Install dependencies of used namespaced packages

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

Let's say I have the following package structure:

```
package/
    mynamespace-subpackage-a/
        setup.py
        mynamespace/
            subpackage_a/
                __init__.py

    mynamespace-subpackage-b/
        setup.py
        mynamespace/
            subpackage_b/
                __init__.py
            module_b.py
```

with setup.py in package a:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='mynamespace-subpackage-a',
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    namespace_packages=['mynamespace'],
    install_requires=['pandas']
)
```

and package b:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='mynamespace-subpackage-b',
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    namespace_packages=['mynamespace'],
    install_requires=[]
)
```

package b uses package a, but it does not have any references to the pandas library itself. So it is not listed in the install_requires, but should still be installed when `pip install .` is executed inside package b and package a should be packaged along with it.

What should be added in the second `setup` file to achieve and is this even possible? Or should `pandas` be in the requirement list of package b as well?

I would suspect something like:

```
install_requires = ['mynamespace.subpackage_a`]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from the question, I believe it should be:

`package/mynamespace-subpackage-b/setup.py`:

```
#...
setup(
    name='mynamespace-subpackage-b',
    # ...
    install_requires=[
        'mynamespace-subpackage-a',
        # ...
    ],
)
```

This obviously assumes that *pip* can found `a` when installing `b`, meaning a distribution of `a` should be published on some kind of index (such as PyPI for example). If it is not possible then maybe one of the following alternatives could help:

- Place distributions of `a` and `b` (*wheel* or *source distribution*) in a local directory, and then use *pip*'s `--find-links` option ([doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages)): `pip install --find-links=path/to/distributions mynamespace-subpackage-b`
- Use a [*direct reference file URL* as seen in *PEP 440*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references): `install_requires=['a @ file:///path/to/a.whl']`
- Use a [*direct remote URL*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) (*VCS* such as *git* would work) the URL could be to a private repository or on the local file system: `install_requires=['mynamespace-subpackage-a @ git+file:///path/to/mynamespace-subpackage-a@master']`, this assumes `setup.py` is at the root of the repository.

Comment: This works if I first do a pip install of `mynamespace-subpackage-a`, but can it work without that

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue... -- This obviously assumes that _pip_ can found `a` when installing `b`, meaning a distribution of `a` should be published on some kind of index (such as _PyPI_ for example), or this could be solved with an explicit link to a distribution of `a` on the local file system.

Comment: The issue: pip should find `a` when installing `b`, without having to install `a` first and without having it available on PyPI or as an egg on github. So I am looking for a way that `pip install ./b` also executes a `pip install ./a` or something with the same result at least

Comment: I edited my answer to include some ideas on how to let _pip_ know where to find dependencies on the local file system (no need to upload to _PyPI_ or _GitHub_), but there are limitations and might not completely meet your needs. If you can be more explicit about your requirements, I could try to adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: @sampers Does that answer the question? Should we accept it, or do you need some more clarifications?

Comment: What I tried to achieve is not possible which makes sense, you're answer provided insight in that for me. Thanks!